# How to submit a list of jobs to PBS system in a proper way?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pbs

I can only submit 10 jobs to the PBS system at the same time. 
If I have independent 99 scripts, I would like to have a script to finish all these 99 scripts by one click.

```
jobs1.sh
jobs2.sh
jobs3.sh
.
.
jobs99.sh
```

The purpose is to submit another 10 jobs after finishing previous 10 jobs.
Currently, I'm using sleep to separate every 10 jobs by estimating how much time they need. I know it's not a nice way.....

Comment: The job order is random. My main question is how to know if previous 10 jobs finish or not. Then, I can submit another 10 jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check out the PBS section about dependencies. There are good ways of queuing jobs to run after the previous ones have finished. For example-

```
qsub  -W depend=afterok:Job_ID job11.sh
```

Job_ID can be the JOB_ID for job1.sh.

So job11 runs only after job1 has finished. You can elaborate on this idea and set up a loop.

Comment: Thank you. I know PBS dependencies. However, I'm thinking if my job order  is random. Should I just create a hash table to do this ?